# how to access interface on angular

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, components, ng-bootstrap

I have created an interface name Alert that contains (type, message) variables both are strings. I also created a constant named Alerts that contain an array of the Alert interface. when I want to use a variable called 'alerts' to access the interface Alert, I get a runtime error called TS2564: property 'alerts' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor. I have installed ng-bootstrap for my HTML template. Here is my code listed below.

- **contact-form.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    interface Alert {
      type: string;
      message: string;
    }
    
    const ALERTS: Alert[] = [{
      type: 'success',
      message: 'This is an success alert',
    }, {
      type: 'info',
      message: 'This is an info alert',
    }, {
      type: 'warning',
      message: 'This is a warning alert',
    }, {
      type: 'danger',
      message: 'This is a danger alert',
    }, {
      type: 'primary',
      message: 'This is a primary alert',
    }, {
      type: 'secondary',
      message: 'This is a secondary alert',
    }, {
      type: 'light',
      message: 'This is a light alert',
    }, {
      type: 'dark',
      message: 'This is a dark alert',
    }
    ];
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-contact-form',
      templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
    })
    export class ContactFormComponent {
    
    
      alerts: Alert[];
    
    
      constructor() {
        this.reset();
      }
    
      close(alert: Alert) {
        this.alerts.splice(this.alerts.indexOf(alert), 1);
      }
    
      reset() {
        this.alerts = Array.from(ALERTS);
      }
    }
```

- **contact-form.component.html**

```
    <p *ngFor="let alert of alerts">
      <ngb-alert [type]="alert.type" (closed)="close(alert)">{{ alert.message }}</ngb-alert>
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

**- app.component.html**

```
    <app-contact-form></app-contact-form>
```

- **app.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';
    import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ContactFormComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        NgbModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

- **here is my error**

> Error: src/app/contact-form/contact-form.component.ts:43:3 - error
> TS2564: Property 'alerts' has no  initializer and is not definitely
> assigned in the  constructor.
>
> 43   alerts: Alert[];

I am using

1. Angular CLI: 13.0.4
2. Node: 14.15.5
3. Package Manager: npm 6.14.11
4. OS:win32 x64

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve this issue:

Approach 1: Initialize the variable in your ContactFormComponent while declaring its type

```
  alerts: Alert[] = [];
```

Approach 2: Initialize the variable in your ContactFormComponent constructor

```
constructor(name: string) {
    this.alerts = [];
}
```

Approach 3: Add the `?` as a postfix to the variable to mark it as `possibly undefined`.

```
alerts?: Alert[];
```

Comment: I want to argue that approach 3 will cause more harm than good. It causes the compiler to treat the property as not `null` or `undefined`. In this scenario however, the property *is* `undefined` unless initialized properly. My suggestion would be to change the type to `alerts?: Alert[]` (for approach 3).

Comment: @PhilippMeissner Agreed

Comment: Want me to edit the answer? :)

Comment: Please, go for it.